# how to put variable in CURL header using shell script?

Tags: shell-script, shell, curl

I want to call an API using shellscript but I m not able to put header properly...whats going wrong in my script... thanks in advance.

shell script :

```
#!/bin/bash
curl -H "Authorization: Basic ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ" -H "Content-Type: application/xml" -X POST -i -d "" -o session.xml  http://a.b.c.d:xxxx/api/auth/

session=`grep -i x-rest session.xml | head -1 | cut -d ' ' -f 2`

echo $session

set -xxx
curl -H "X-RestSvcSessionId: ${session}" -X GET  "http://a.b.c.d:xxxx/api/jobs"
```

output:

```
<pre>
% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  5475    0  5475    0     0  43457      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 43800

OGIyMDUxYTctNjMzNC00MjhjLWJiOTEtZjQ2YmMwZGY1NmY3

 -X GET http://a.b.c.d:xxxx/api/jobsjMzNC00MjhjLWJiOTEtZjQ2YmMwZGY1NmY3
</pre>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Bad Request</TITLE>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" Content="text/html; charset=us-ascii"></HEAD>
<BODY><h2>Bad Request</h2>
<hr><p>HTTP Error 400. The request is badly formed.</p>
</BODY></HTML>
```

Comment: @Jesse_b  Are you sure about that edit?

Comment: @GerardH.Pille: No but it's better than it was.

Comment: Cannot decide wether this question fits here or is stackoverflow.com material.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro  Move on then, there's nothing here but us chickens.

Comment: yes i m sure. @Jesse_b

Answer (score 3):

The problem is if you SET variable by `curl`, `grep`, `head` or `tail` ++ then you will have a **NEW Line in the END** of your variable.

To remove the NEW Line set your last `curl` with `$session` like:

```
curl -H "X-RestSvcSessionId: ${session//[$'\t\r\n ']}" -X GET  "http://a.b.c.d:xxxx/api/jobs"
```

This will remove the new line and tab (if any).

I had same error: [check here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59342470/bash-script-curl-get-cookie-and-re-use-error-400-request-badly-formed)

Answer (score 0):

"session" contains a carriage return, which ruins your curl request. Replace the grep/head/cut in backticks by:

```
session=$(awk '/^X-RestSvcSessionId/ {print $2}' session.xml)
```

and use the following curl parameter:

```
--cookie "X-RestSvcSessionId=$session"
```

Comment: not working :-(

Comment: Can you publish your session.xml somewhere?

Comment: `HTTP/1.1 201 CREATED
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: application/xml; charset=utf-8
Location: http://W.X.Y.Z:xxxx/api/sessionMngr/abcd-efgh-ijkl-mnop-qrstuvw
Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
X-RestSvcSessionId: NWJlYjVlZWItMWFmOS00YjU0LWJkOWYtNDA5MTA4NjEwODhi
Set-Cookie: X-RestSvcSessionId=NWJlYjVlZWItMWFmOS00YjU0LWJkOWYtNDA5MTA4NjEwODhi; Path=/api;
Date: Tue, 27 Feb 2018 13:47:46 GMT`

Comment: Put it at least in your question, that some of the formatting remains.  But this wiill still remove any special characters that you don't see.

Comment: My mistake, bash starts a subshell for the pipe, so the variable session is lost after the read.

Comment: still not working :-(

Comment: You need to send a cookie back, see my answer.